# Vlan config for switches

Tags: switch, vlan

I am adding 4 HP switches into an environment with vlans. I need to separate 2 data networks and 1 voice network. I am rusty on the tagging, untagged and trunk needs. Each vlan will have its own subnet. If all ports come untagged with a default vlan 1 and I need 15 ports to be on a separate vlan do I just tag them with vlan 2 and leave the untagged on or do I have to remove them from untagged?

Does each uplink port need to be trunked or can I just tag the port with all vlans

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember on HP switches the trunk is defined by having multiple tagged vlans. If you need a native vlan on the "trunk" depends on your setup (what does the other end expect?). Note that I have never configured voice vlans on a HP and I am not sure how they support it but based on [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/409714-hp-procurve-vlan-configuration-for-voip) it seems that they require tagged traffic. I would propose the following:

- Keep your up-links tagged (I tend to use ports at the end)
- Voice is also tagged based on the above link
- Data will always be untagged on access ports (servers might be an exception - this is mainly for desktops)
- Switch has IP only on the management vlan which is assumed to be id=1
- Do not expose management (mgmt) vlan if you can avoid it

So for a 24-port switch we have something like (comments after `#`...):

```
vlan 1 
   name "mgmt" 
   tagged 23-24 # uplinks
   ip address X.X.X.X 255.255.255.0 
   no untagged 1-22 # leaving 2 uplinks
   exit 

vlan 2
   name "voice"
   tagged 1-24 # Includes uplinks
   qos priority 6 # based on the previous post...
   voice
   exit 

vlan 41
   name "data 1" 
   untagged 1-15 # your 15 ports
   no ip address 
   tagged 23-24 # uplinks
   exit 

vlan 42
   name "data 2" 
   no ip address
   untagged 16-22 # ... whatever is left
   tagged 23-24 
   exit
```

Hope it helps

Comment: !!! I just noticed that the question is very old !!!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer in Cisco terms.

Any connection that connects two switches together should be configured as a trunk.  I don't know if HP allows it, but you can change which VLANs are allowed to be transported on that trunk.

You should also be able to set up a native VLAN.  The native VLAN is the VLAN that transports untagged traffic.

Configure your access ports (the ones connecting the PC's to the switch) with the appropriate VLAN.

Remember, if you want to communicate between VLANs, you will need an Inter-VLAN routing solution (such as a router or a layer 3 switch)

Generally, you can only tag a switchport with one access VLAN, and one voice VLAN.